# Android, Bluetooth, getBoundedDevices returns empty list

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have problem in my application that basically should connect Arduino via Bluetooth and send information. First of all, I want to show user a list of devices with Bluetooth around, so user can choose one and try to connect. But here starts the problem: getBoundedDevices() on BluetoothAdapter returns empty list. I checked devices around thought few apps on few phones: there always was some devices that are visible in Bluetooth, however my application doesn't shows that.
Below I attached the code of my fragment that is responsible for working with Bluetooth (I don't really like Stack code highlighting, so I pasted it to Pastebin):
[Code](http://pastebin.com/1yX6pJ5C)

I didn't found any information about problem like this over internet and I wrote it pretty much like any tutorial about working with Bluetooth on Android.

## Update:

Thanks to kcoppock I've resolved issue. Final version of code, for someone who could have same problems in future, can be found here:
[Final version](http://pastebin.com/kxGGyDS8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(
        broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

You're registering using the `LocalBroadcastManager` (which is meant for limiting the scope of broadcasts that you send to only your application). Registering on this broadcast manager won't receive system broadcasts.

You should register using the `Activity's` `registerReceiver`method:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, ...);
```

This assumes that your fragment is always attached to a host activity (probably safer to null-check `getActivity`, and to do this from `onResume()` instead of `onCreateView()`).

Don't forget to unregister the receiver, as well! In the equivalent tear down method (e.g. if you use `onResume()`, tear down in `onPause()`), add:

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: I already tryed this way with no success. I will try again, just to make sure, and then will let you know.

Comment: Wow, this actually resolved issue. I suppose when I last time tested it: I wasn't called blutoothAdapter.startDiscovery() so it just didn't search for devices around. Thank you for your help.